# c++ file will not compile with a certain #include while all others do

Tags: c++, linux

I have a c++ file that keeps throwing errors about four files up the chain, while every other file using that #include compiles fine.

It keeps giving me this kind of stuff. I am certain the include file is fine as 1. All of the others which use this same file compile fine and 2. I looked at the file, and it is fine.

```
/usr/include/opal/opal/mediafmt.h:305:9: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
/usr/include/opal/opal/mediafmt.h:305:9: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/opal/opal/mediafmt.h:305:9: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
/usr/include/opal/opal/mediafmt.h:308:14: error: bit-field ‘mode’ with non-integral type
```

It's odd because it throws the error about 5 files up the chain:

```
In file included from /usr/include/opal/opal/connection.h:44:0,
             from /usr/include/opal/opal/call.h:41,
             from /usr/include/opal/opal/manager.h:42,
             from /usr/include/opal/opal/endpoint.h:41,
             from /usr/include/opal/opal/localep.h:41,
             from /home/jonathan/workspace/HHPVideoServer/opal/GstEndPoint.h:12,
             from /home/jonathan/workspace/HHPVideoServer/opal/opal-call-manager.h:42,
             from ../gui/HHPVideoCodecGui.cc:3:
```

I checked to make sure I wasn't screwing up any #define s but that was the only idea I had. Is there a good approach someone can offer me on how to track this error down?

Here is the file:

http://www.opalvoip.org/docs/opal-v3_9/da/d60/mediafmt_8h-source.html

**Update**

Here is the struct with the troublesome line from the preprocessor. I suppose the "0L" is the trouble.

```
struct H245GenericInfo {
  H245GenericInfo() { memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this)); }
  unsigned ordinal:16;
  enum Modes {
    0L,
    Collapsing,
    NonCollapsing
  } mode:3;
  enum IntegerTypes {
    UnsignedInt,
    Unsigned32,
    BooleanArray
  } integerType:3;
  bool excludeTCS:1;
  bool excludeOLC:1;
  bool excludeReqMode:1;
};
```

then

```
#define None 0L
```

from "/usr/include/X11/X.h" causes 0L to be substituted for None in the Modes enumeration at line 305.

from the X11 lib. The reason the other files were compiling is that they weren't also using Gtk. Does any one have a work around that doesn't involve me rewriting either of the lib files?

**solution**

I just put the offending #include above everything else. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: I know you said that the file is fine, but please, humor us with it's contents.

Comment: Look for a missing semicolon in one of the files.

Comment: Good guess on the missing semicolon. Or possibly a missing closing brace.

Comment: sure, its really long though.

Comment: Just post the lines where the error is, or put it up on pastebin or gist.github.com.

Comment: line 305 is in the middle of an enum definition.

Comment: @Casper see my edit for the file.

Comment: `None` looks like a very suspicious candidate for a `#define` somewhere else. I'd run the `gcc -E` suggestion from Keith and then locate the line for `enum Modes` in the `tmpfile`..you'll probably see something weird there.

Comment: probably u r getting error bcoz u r trying to access the `mode` variable   `enum Modes {
        None,
        Collapsing,
        NonCollapsing
      } mode:3` which has size of  3 bits only...

Comment: @Casper I am looking now. That is a nifty trick.

Comment: @Jonathan - Do you also want some hints on memset being illegal in a constructor? You can only use memset on PODs and PODs do not have a constructor.

Comment: @Bo, seeing as how that code isn't mine, I won't be changing it unless I join the OPAL voip project. However, I still like to know. Thanks. I'll email the author about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using gcc, run `gcc -E your-file.c > tmpfile`.  This runs just the preprocessor.  The output is going to be quite voluminous, but it should help you track down the problem.

What does line 305 look like?

EDIT:
Given your update, yes, the problem is that "None" is being defined as a macro before your mediafmt.h tries to define it as an enumerator.  Can you add `#undef None` after including X.h and before including mediafmt.h?  (If so, be sure to comment it.)

EDIT2: Rearranging the `#include` directives might be a better solution -- but again, be sure to add a comment explaining the reason.

Comment: Yes, I can add that. Which is better practice, using #undef or rearranging the #includes?

Comment: @Jonathan: Hmm, interesting question.  Better practice would have been for `/usr/include/X11/X.h` not to define `None` as a macro, but I guess we're stuck with that.  I'd say rearranging the `#include`s is probably cleaner, as long as the revised order doesn't make things too ugly.  But again, be sure to add a comment explaining it, so someone else doesn't come along and rearrange them again.

Comment: Thanks! I am glad I had this problem as I learned several things I didn't know about c/c++ and gcc.

Comment: @Jonathan: Another thing to learn is that there is no language called c/c++.  C and C++ are closely related, but they're best thought of as two distinct language.  Much well-written C code is legal C++, but it's generally not *well-written* C++.  And there are rarely good reasons to write code that will compile as both.  (The term "c/c++" is a bit of a pet peeve of mine.)

Comment: I don't mean by c/c++ that they are the same language, and I understand their difference. I say c/c++ when a principle applies to both. What I learned about #include order and how to read the preprocessor applies to both. Plus, this code base is a conglomeration between the two. I have c and c++ code. Also, some of the libs I am linking to are in C. Anyhow, I hear ya.

Comment: @Jonathan: Great.  Unfortunately, some people do seem to think there's a mythical language called "C/C++".

Answer (score 2):

Because you said that this include works from other files, I'm guessing that the order of your #includes may be different in the failing file.  Try moving the #include for opal-call-manager.h to the top of the file.

Ideally, you would follow the answers others have posted to track down the root cause, but simply reordering the #includes may be a quick solution and will help narrow down what is conflicting.

Comment: Thanks! putting it at the top of the file, was the final trick I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Since you found `0L` in place of `None` it's likely you have `#define None 0L` somewhere in your include chain. Either reorder the includes, like Klox suggested, so this definition happens **after** `mediafmt.h` is included, or try and convert, undefine, or fix the offending `None` definition elsewhere.